# Changing user nickname after join from database discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I wonder if you can help (i search it and nothing)
I am learning how to work with discord.js and i want to change user nickname after they join.
It should be like this: Someone join my discord server from my website (there are registration with id system ) after they join bot change his name like this ( "ID from website" - "his nickname" ). Example: ( 1 - kapacitta )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event and the [`GuildMember.setNickname()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname) function:

```js
// will emmit when a user joins a server
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
 const newNick = (...); // fetch string from database
 member.setNickname(newNick); // set nickname
});
```

Comment: sorry, how can i fetch from database. I am begginer :D

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MariaDB.

Comment: [`MariaDB` documentation](https://mariadb.org/documentation/#getting-started)